# How netcat's -e functionality work?

Tags: network, tools

I want to know how netcat uses -e parameter to serve executable over TCP/IP?
I want to write it on Python to understand it deeper, but I don't know how it is doing it?
If I am not mistaken, It is using windows API, if it is which kind of API is used by Netcat?

Comment: First, netcat is open source, you could just read the code. Second, you are making an assumption that it is using a Windows API. Third, from the man page, all it does is run an executable locally once a network connection is made. This isn't a big mystery on how to do that: `if network_connection then run $command` Fourth, this isn't a security question.

Comment: @schroeder First, if I could read and understand code better , I would not write here as question. Second, yes I made assumption, but I don't know if it works and how to implement , so I asked from others. You said this is not big mystery, just  "if network_connection then run $command" , right? Could u write it? (I suppose you don't ) Fourth this is security question of course. Do I have to write it on programmers forum ? They even don't know what is netcat. I just asked how can I implement, maybe someone can help me.

Comment: Btw, please revert my topic to its original state, I saw that you said ""This question does not appear to be about Information security within the scope defined in the help center."  Are u sure? read that topics again, there have been written topics called "security tools" and "penetration testing" . Revert it or I will write it to stack's official mail.

Answer (score 1):

From the man page:

```
   -e command, --exec command (Execute command) .
       Execute the specified command after a connection has been established. The command must
       be specified as a full pathname. All input from the remote client will be sent to the
       application and responses sent back to the remote client over the socket, thus making
       your command-line application interactive over a socket. Combined with --keep-open,
       Ncat will handle multiple simultaneous connections to your specified port/application
       like inetd. Ncat will only accept a maximum, definable, number of simultaneous
       connections controlled by the -m option. By default this is set to 100 (60 on Windows).
```

It just runs `/bin/bash <command> <params>` on the remote host. No executable is transferred, but only local executables are run.

Comment: I know it bro, my main question is how it is doing it ? I want to get answer from programming perspective. Especially on windows

Comment: @Abdulla Please you formal language. Ontopic: netcat calls either execv (or variants) on Unix-like systems or `CreateProcess()` / `ShellExecute()` on Windows.

Comment: Could u give me example ? Or reference? Either in C or Python